# ClassNotFoundException: MysqlDataSource

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, gradle, hikaricp

(embedded Tomcat 7.0.59, gradle 2.13, HikariCP 2.4.6, mysql-connector-java 6.0.2)

I want to create connection pool (mysql) in my web application. 
When I execute gradle tomcatRun, I get the following message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.UtilityElf.createInstance(UtilityElf.java:89)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:294)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:91)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:101)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:71)
    at [my package].DbContextListener.initDataSource(DbContextListener.java:40)
    at [my package].DbContextListener.contextInitialized(DbContextListener.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.UtilityElf.createInstance(UtilityElf.java:76)
    ... 15 more
```

I found that tomcat may not contain dbcp-jar, so I tried to add it via gradle:
`compile 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:7.0.59'` but nothing changed

Can anyone explain me how it should be done?

Comment: Why have you tagged hikaricp if your problem is with DBCP?

Comment: I guess if you will provide your code fragment that would be more helpful then just error messages.